# Intent seems has no data, does it have any applications?

Tags: android, android-intent, adb, intentfilter

ADB can be used to send broadcast intent by for example:

> adb shell am broadcast -a com.whereismywifeserver.intent.TEST --es
>   sms_body "test from adb"

where: `-a` is the action and `-es` is the extra string. My thought is that the action parameter is necessary, since it is used by the intent receiver to receive the intent using (intent filter). However, I noticed that we can send intent without specifying the action for example:

> adb shell am broadcast -n com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.AlarmInitReceiver

Why this is possible? Isn't an empty intent? and any applications of such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't an empty intent?

No. `-n` creates an explicit `Intent`, one that identifies the application ID (`com.google.android.deskclock`) and the component (`com.android.deskclock.AlarmInitReceiver`). Using an explicit `Intent` directly delivers the `Intent` to the designated component; in your case, via a broadcast.

> and any applications of such thing?

Explicit `Intents` are used widely in Android, perhaps even more commonly than are implicit `Intents`. Examples include:

- Tapping on a home screen launcher icon (`startActivity()` with an explicit `Intent`)
- `JobService` and other specialized service classes (`bindService()` with an explicit `Intent`)
- `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` (`sendBroadcast()` with an explicit `Intent`)